# How to recursively check each KPI in JSON

Tags: java, json

I wants to put logic on each KPI value. So, where ever I found "KPI" I will put that in strKey like in below I wants to put "Directs" in first iteration and in second iteration "Process". Post that implement some logic.

```
{
"kpis": [
  {  
     "KPI":"Directs",
     "definition":{  
        "type":{  
           "exec":"aggregate"
                },
        "result":{  
           "columns":[  
              "Month",
              "Last Touch Marketing Channel"
           ]
        }
     }
  },
  {  
     "KPI":"Process",
     "definition":{  
        "type":{  
           "exec":"aggregate"
                },
        "result":{  
           "columns":[  
              "Month",
              "Last Touch Marketing Channel"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

javacode

```
JSONTokener objJSONTokener = new JSONTokener(objFileReader);
JSONObject objJSONRoot = (JSONObject) objJSONTokener.nextValue();
JSONObject objElement;
JSONObject thisDefinition;
String strKey;
java.util.Iterator<String> objDictionary = objJSONRoot.keys();
while (objDictionary.hasNext()) {
          strKey = objDictionary.next();
          //to do..
       }
```

Comment: That's the start of a solution. What's the problem?

Comment: in the current logic strKey is storing "kpi" array where as I wants to get the Value of "KPI" which is 'Directs'